# Django Storing Website Content

Tags: django

I'm a bit new to web development and am having trouble understanding how site content is stored. Even after looking at open source projects, I am still confused.

Lets say that I have a web page with multiple paragraphs that I am hoping to eventually be able to edit through the Django admin page. Now, I have the view set up for the page but I am unsure as how the models should be structured.

So far I have:

```
from django.db import models

class content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_updated = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

'name' is what my paragraphs will be talking about and 'content' should be all the paragraphs on that page. My question: Should the content field be stored in HTML or should I just store purely text? If it is pure text, how will I be able to add the HTML formatting when I embed the model.content field into my template? Wouldn't this be difficult see as I would need to parse the pure text to do so?

However, if I store HTML in the content field, wouldn't I have to use HTML when entering content or use a WYSIWYG editor in the admin page?

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In admin, you can use a WYSIWIG editor like [TinyMCE](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/)
This would store the content as HTML. While rendering - you can do `{{content|safe}}`.

Look into [django-flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/?from=olddocs). it does exactly what you are shooting for.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the benefits of storing 'flatpages' in a database as opposed to just leaving them as static pages in your '/static/' folder? Is there any performance benefit or does it just reduce the amount of space taken by the static content? For content that does not dynamically change, how do I know the line between when I should save the content to a database and when I should hard-code it into a template?

Comment: static content is already present as a part of django contrib. Lesser code to write, and maintain. Plus, flatpages  are very light weight.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [django-tinymce](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Its a good package which provides a [widget](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#using-the-widget) to be associated with a `CharField` in forms for front-end and a [model field](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#the-htmlfield-model-field-type) to displayed as a `WYSIWYG` editor in admin.

And yes it will store the text content as html in database.