# How to let website admin save new content

Tags: django, database, web

I'm starting to develop a web page for my friend's band using Django and sqlite, deploying to nginx server. However, this question is probably for web development in general.

I want to allow him to save new content for the pages through the web site itself, probably in html-format. How should I implement it?

Saving to a database seems to me misuse of database, because the data is not relational and there's very limited amount of it. What approach should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a CMS, and CMSs do definitely store their content in the database. There is no reason *not* to, especially as Django is already set up to easily read from and write to a database.

Comment: I found this very related question to my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007033/django-storing-website-content